# How to set zero flag

Tags: c++, x86

```
LONG WINAPI MyUnhandledExceptionFilter(PEXCEPTION_POINTERS p)
{

    if(p->ExceptionRecord->ExceptionCode==EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION){
        if(p->ContextRecord->Eip==6F3A15FD){
            p->ContextRecord->EFlags
        }
```

i want my exception handler to set zero flag if exception occured in a specified address ;)
how do i do it `p->ContextRecord->EFlags|=` ??

also if i just give `EXCEPTION_CONTINUE_EXECUTION` after access violation will it work ? :D and, do i have to inc the EIP or it will fall on next instruction ?

Comment: There will come a time in which a programmer will be sent to jail for doing (or just trying to do) things like this.

Comment: @6502: I think you've forgotten to include a smiley.

Comment: i know its not the way to do it just i dont have the nerves or IDA skill to fix this fully :P

Comment: @Alex: indeed I'm serious. I didn't say I like it (I don't)... I just said I think there will be laws against this.

Comment: @6502: Against using exceptions and exception handlers?

Comment: @Alex: about circumventing safety features like access violation exceptions or about patching executables. UK a few years ago even passed a law about **possessing** network admin tools (yes, there was no need to be caught using them maliciously... just having them on your system would make you liable and yes, this apparently included things like netcat or wireshark). You should not be too optimistic about how bad political decisions can be.

Comment: @6502: didnt know that, fail much. IMHO according to that law all antivirus users would have to be imprisoned :P It hooks system api's, reverse engineers programs. evil.

Comment: This looks like war3 hacker

Comment: @OpenThread funny you got a conclusion exactly opposite to the truth ;) (if I understand your usage of the word hacker correctly)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ZF` is bit 6 of `EFLAGS`, so `EFlags |= 1 << 6;`

Download Intel's or AMD's CPU manual. You'll find all this info there.

Comment: and will it continue to next instruction ? or repeat that one ;F

Comment: If your filter returns `EXCEPTION_CONTINUE_EXECUTION`, the faulted instruction will be repeated. If it returns `EXCEPTION_CONTINUE_SEARCH`, the exception will propagate further, but if this is the last filter, your program will be terminated.